# Remote Desktop between two Windows PC, but RaspberryPi in between

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rasberrypi

We have a RaspberryPi with direct access to our companies internal network (the mac-address is registered with IT). We also have a Windows 10 PC, which we would like to access via remote desktop (or similar), but without registering (because our department has to pay for each additional registered MAC). The PC by itself doesn't need to have access to the company's network, so we thought we could connect the RPi via LAN to the network and connecting the PC either via a second LAN-cable or USB to the RPi and then access the PC by something like forwarding the remote request. Now we are not network-guys but software-developers and electrical engineers, and when googling for "remote desktop between two windows and a RPi in between", the results only answer Win-RP or RP-Win. Does anyone have experience with such a setup and can share some insides on how to do that (if possible)?

Update 1:
[Small illustration of the setup I try to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jll0f.png)

Comment: Put the Raspberry Pi on your network the same as any other device. This frees up access to the Windows 10 machine but it can still access the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What is the end goal of connecting the Windows machine to this device? It wouldn’t be able to access the network because of the network configuration you described

Comment: I've updated the question with a small illustration. What I try is be able to connect to the workstation via the RPi from HomeOffice, when i'm in the VPN. The Workstation, not part of the Network is only reachable via the RPi (and prob. no internet access on it's own). This way, we only need to register the RPi (making is visible inside the VPN) but can also work with the Workstation (from home) not registered by itself.